# How to access SAP WSDL service in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wsdl

A client has given SAP-based WSDL service. In WSDL I don't know what are the methods, request parameters and response. Please tell me how to call WSDL in asp.net?

Comment: trying to get a SAP stack exchange started, check it out here http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41621/sap-systems-applications-and-products

Answer (score 4):

Follow these steps:

1. Select Project > Add Service Reference
2. Paste WSDL File
3. Click on Go

Usage:

```
var serviceClient = new ServiceReferenceName.ClassClient();
serviceClient.Do();
```

You also need to update config file with the server URL:

```
<client>
  <endpoint address="http://UrlFromYourCustomerHere"
            binding="basicHttpBinding"
            bindingConfiguration="xxx"
            contract="MyServiceReference.xxx"
            name="xxx/>
</client>
```

An example of calling method:

```
[WebMethod]
public static List<string> GetFileListOnWebServer()
{
   DirectoryInfo dInfo = new DirectoryInfo(HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/UploadedFiles/"));
   FileInfo[] fInfo = dInfo.GetFiles("*.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);

   List<string> listFilenames = new List<string>(fInfo.Length);

   for(int i = 0; i < fInfo.Length; i++)
   {
        listFilenames.Add(fInfo[i].Name);
   }

   return listFilenames;
}
```

This will return file names in a list, that goes to a folder.

When you add a web reference it create a proxy class in your project that has the same or similar methods/arguments as your web service.

Comment: Thanks,i followed your steps but how to call a method  in service reference and how to send the request parameters and how to get response any sample for better understnading?

Comment: @user1965546, edited my answer, Request and response are being called by this method. You get file names in return after requesting through `Getfiles`.

Comment: how do I paste the WSDL file? There's no place for that. I'm using VS 2013.

Comment: @ataravati, you don't need that. Simply add service reference and then insert location. Then you will get WSDL file auto generated according to the service operations.

Comment: I got it. Thanks!